# Node symbol lookup error opencv

Tags: c++, node.js, opencv

I am currently writing a C++ module for node that uses open cv, and I encountered an issue that I do not quite understand.  Basically this is the method that I am trying to add

```
    void GetPuzzle(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
        v8::String::Utf8Value parameter(args[0]->ToString());
        std::string filePath = std::string(*parameter);
        Mat puzzle = imread("sudoku.jpg", 0);
   }
```

Just to make sure that the included open cv is working properly. `node-gyp build`  works, exits with an ok , however when I am actually running the server.js file I get the following exception :

```
node: symbol lookup error: /home/dave/Projects/puzzlesolver/build/Release/sudokuGrabber.node: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6imreadERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEi
```

This is the include of the opencv :

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

I guess this info is important for solving the issue - I am working on linux (ubuntu). Any suggestion of what is wrong with my code and what could I do to fix it ?

Comment: How have you attempted to link opencv to your module?

Comment: I sort of just did that include , my guess was that if node-gyp build isn't throwing errors then it is linked .

Comment: Just because it compiled doesn't mean you have linked in all the necessary libraries.

Comment: Oops , my main language is a managed one , I don't really know cpp, so I assumed that the compiler would at least notify me if a lib is missing. What should I add to binding.gyp ?